# My project contains Fragment which displays Grid of Images. I know to display all the images, but i want to display only few images , how?

Tags: android, gridview

```
1. 
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    // Displaying Grid of Images in GridView.
    private GridView gridView;
    // Using ArrayList for drawable Images.
    ArrayList<Drawable> allDrawableImages = new ArrayList<>();
    private TypedArray allImages;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // Return the rootView of Grid Images
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        getAllWidgets(rootView);
        setAdapter();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void getAllWidgets(View view) {
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewFragmentOne);
        allImages = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.all_images);
    }

    private void setAdapter()
    {
        // Displaying Images from Drawable folder.
        // Adding the Images to Grid from Drawable folder
        for (int i = 0; i < allImages.length(); i++) {
            allDrawableImages.add(allImages.getDrawable(i));
        }

        // Drawing Images using ImageAdapter into activity
        // Displaying Images into GridView.
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.getInstance(), allDrawableImages);
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    } 
}
```

// This is the code , how to edit the code in ArrayList to show only the Images which i want to display.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a filtered list? Create a new `ArrayList` (`List<>`) and add items from the original in a for loop to it that you want to keep. If your list keeps changing on the fly a lot, do this in a custom `Adapter` to avoid recreating the `Adapter` all the time.

Or just simply here put in your list the images you want to display:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allImages.length(); i++) {
    if (iWantToDisplayImage(i)) {
        allDrawableImages.add(allImages.getDrawable(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh , that's great , as i am new to coding i am least at transforming logic into code . Can u please show me how to do that ArrayList.

Comment: Check the edit, I don't know based on what you want to display the images, but just put a condition in your loop.